# Firebase: Is it possible to send emails on from user's email address?

Tags: firebase, react-native, flutter, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions

I am new to Firebase and this might sound a bit crazy but our app has a requirement where it needs users to link their email and give us send permission from their account. I know it's possible using Google APIs but I am not sure how to achieve this. Our app is written in React Native but we're moving to Flutter and I was wondering if sending from user's email is something Firebase can handle. Is there a cloud function or something which lets us ask user's consent for sending on their behalf and then just sending emails using their email address, a feature in app requires this and I am not sure how to implement this in React Native or Flutter using Firebase. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Does your app only support signing in with a google account or you support multiple identity providers ?

Comment: Hi @Karthik thanks for taking time to help me out here. For now it only supports signing in with a Google account but we have plans to add more. In face we haven't even implemented the Google sign in either yet as we're exploring options to pick the best one that works.

Comment: Got it, I posted an answer below that is specific to what an app that supports signing in with Google would need to do. But this interaction is based on a standard called OAuth and I don’t think it would be much different if in the future say you want to support Microsoft accounts I guess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can either do it using a function with the necessary trigger in firebase or just from your flutter app.
The assumption here is that a user authorized your app and grants the Send permission.

If your app supports signing in with google, and is an installed app then you would follow this workflow.
[image: Installed Apps Workflow]

See: https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2InstalledApp

Make sure you include the right scope for the permission you need. See list of Gmail scopes here https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/auth/scopes